# Calculateing the MOS size for this amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, amplifier, circuit-design

The MOS size is the key to let them be in the saturation region,i just know the size of M1 = M2,but i have no idea of calculating the other MOS size,can anyone give me some clue,or are there some examples for calculating ?

[image]

Comment: Hmm, here's a list of things which determine the geometry of a MOS transistors when used in a circuit: process technology, bias current, required matching/mismatch, bandwidth of circuit, required noise. You see: lots of things. So it is **impossible** to answer what you ask as you have not provided all this information. And if you had then it would become a design job which no one here is going to do for you.

Comment: I understand that as a beginner you want to "calculate everything" well, that's not how circuit design works. Very often you should just start with a certain size and then work from there. After you have done more designs you will know from experience what value of W/L to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Make all FETs W=10/L=1, and operate at current large enough to cause 0.1volt effective voltage (Vgs-Vt = 0.1).